# Enable Sticky Edges Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, 20.04

I recently upgraded to **Ubuntu 20.04** and i can't find any way to enable **Sticky Edges**, what i want is for the cursor to briefly stop on the edge before crossing over to the second monitor i don't know if sticky edges is the right term for it but that's what i found, somewhere else was referred to as cursor barrier.

What i have tried:

- displays settings don't have this option anymore
- gnome tweak tools, could not find anything here either
- dconf gnome shell overrides, only have edge tiling but this seems a different feature and even when enabled doesnt give me the behaviour i want

Any clue on how to do this on ubuntu 20.04?

(i can add screenshots of the things i have tried in case you think it should be in one of the things i already tried)

Comment: What happens if you *search* for it inside the Settings application? Does anything show up?

Comment: if i search `edge` nothing shows up, if i search `sticky` it shows me Universal Access, but when i click in it i cant see the word anywhere, or anything that would do what i want

Comment: Is your system detecting multiple monitors correctly? Various options specific to multiple monitors don't appear in the Settings app until the system actually detects the presence of multiple monitors.

Comment: I think so, i can select wich one is the primary, is this enough to say it detected multiple monitors?

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to this right now. I am using 18.04 and this is not possible as I see.
But there is a workaround. When you set your screens under Settings->Displays, you can adjust the screen a bit moved to under and upper sides (not side by side), by this way since the screens are not exactly side by side, the corners of your screens become un-passable. So you can snap your mouse there. But the problem is, you can't pass to the other side from there.
[image: example]
As you see, my second screen is larger, so I can't pass from 2 to 1 from the bottom side, and I moved my first screen a bit upper, so I can't pass to the other side from there. So, you kinda have this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dock to simulate the sticky behaviour. If your monitor A is on the left of monitor B, and you place the dock on the left, you will get the "sticky behaviour" from monitor B to A.

This is working like that just if you use the "auto-hide dock" feature ( you can find it in "Appereance".

Comment: I was trying to disable sticky edges for months now. Although it was disabled in the settings I still had it. Auto hiding dock turns out to be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I wondered where 'Sticky Edges' checkbox had gone too.. so pleased someone asked this already. Solution is easier than I thought.

Sticky works on outside edges of both monitors (x-left & x-right) by default but the inner edges don't bind.

Discovered by accident that dragging window across threshold between monitors will create a 'snap' halo in much the same way a sticky edge would.

If the halo is snapped to the wrong side, make a slight move to correctly align it on the desired monitor & then release mouse button.

Sticky is stuck.